# Is it easier to beat a Pokemon that's twice as high at low or high CP values?

Tags: pokemon-go

The situation is that myself and several friends are going around trying to capture some gyms. Some gyms are already on our team so we train them up in order for us all to be able to place our Pokemon at the gym. Since we are a group we have the option for one of us to put in a Pokemon that we can use to train against (and leave after defeating that first one).

Is it better to put in a low CP Pokemon at around 20 CP for us to defeat using 10 CP Pokemon for the maximum prestige gain or is it easier to defeat a 1200 CP with a 600 CP?

Comment: From personal experience, if you have like a 1100 vaporeon, you can absolutely demolish a 2200 arcanine

Comment: Speed wins this (and ofc type). Low CP like Jolteon can deal a lot of pain in higher tiers.

Comment: @dragonrage yeh but would it be just as easy for a CP 110 vaporeon to defeat a 220 arcanine?

Answer (score 1):

The game's battle system seems to revolve around ratios, so a 20CP vs 10CP battle should be the same difficulty as a 1200CP vs 600CP battle. The main difference would be the 20CP vs 1200CP pokemon that gets left behind once you're finished training the gym.

Comment: Also the type of potions you are burning.